# backtracking line search parameter

Tags: optimization

I am reading/practicing a bit with optimization using Nocedal&Wright, when I got the the simple backtracking algorithm, where if d is my line direction and a is the step size the algorithm looks for a such that

[image]

for some 0 < c < 1. They advised to use a very small c, order of 10^-4.

That seemed very odd to me, as a very loss demand.

I did some experimenting with c = 0.3 and it seemed to work much better then the sugested 10^-4 ( for a simple quadratic problem and steepest descent).

Any intuition as to why such a low value should work and why didn't it do well for me?

Thanks.

Comment: could you add tags `gradient-descent` and `mathematical-optimization` please

Answer (score 0):

∇ f() may have completely different scales for different problems;
one stepsize cannot fit all.
Consider f(x) = sin( ω . x ): the right `c` will depend on ω,
which may be on the order of 1, or 1e-6, or ...
Thus it's a good idea to scale ∇ f() to about norm 1, *then* play with `c`.
(People who recommend "c = ...", please describe your problem size and scales.)

Add some noise to your quadratic, see what happens as you increase the noise.
Try quadratic + noise in 2d, 10d.

In machine learning, there seems to be quite a lot of folklore on `c` a.k.a. learning rate;
google
[learning-rate on stackexchange.com](http://google.com/search?q=learning-rate+site%3astackexchange.com) ,
also [gradient-descent step-size](http://google.com/search?q=gradient-descent+step-size)
and [adagrad](http://google.com/search?q=adagrad) adaptive gradient.